# Trying to redirect to the same page but with querystring value

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect to the same page, but add some querystring values.

If there is already a querystring value, I want to strip it out and add a new one.

My code isn't working currently, not sure why:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
  url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
} else {
    url += "?joined=true";
}
window.location.replace(url);
```

Comment: As an aside, note that `.indexOf()` returns -1 if the substring isn't found, so normally you'd use a condition `> -1` or `!= -1`. (It doesn't matter for this example, because your URL isn't going to have a `?` as its first character, but still...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're not adding the new query string when you strip off the old one, only in the `else` clause when there's no old query string. Take that addition out of the `else`, so you do it all the time.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
  url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
} 
url += "?joined=true";
window.location.replace(url);
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be better to use the already-available `URL` API.

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.set('joined', true);
window.location.replace(url.toString());
```

You can check the following links to learn more about it:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: beware: URL is not supported by IE

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (forget about IE)